Should the runtime version be included in the block header by default?
If I retrieve a block and want to decode it, I have to know what version of the runtime's metadata to use. With only having the block header (or maybe the full block) is there any way I can decode it without having to make another rpc call to figure out the runtime version in use for that block?
Is there a good reason people haven't put it in the block header?
Related question: How do I check what metadata version a chain is running?

You can just query the :code using the hash of the header. You need to get the runtime any way from somewhere. So, I don't see how you need more calls.
